# HashMap and EditText.setEnabled()

Tags: android, android-edittext, hashmap

I am new to Android programming and learning to build Mobile apps. Using Android Studio and came across this issue.
I have a `HashMap` that contains `EditText` as value.  However, when I `.get()` and then try to `.setEnabled()` the `EditText` it throws an exception/error.

If I set the `EditText` to a variable and then `.setEnabled()` it works fine.  What is the difference?

CODE:

```
public static HashMap<String,EditText> GUESTS = new HashMap<String,EditText)();

GUESTS.put("CRAFT", ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.crafteGuest));

EditText craftGuest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.craftGuest);
craftGuest.setEnabled("true"); // this works

GUESTS.get("CRAFT").setEnabled("true"); // this does NOT work
```

Any thoughts?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getTag().toString()) {
        case "CRAFT" : {
            if (!GUESTS.containsKey("CRAFT")) {
                GUESTS.put("CRAFT", ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.craftGuest)));
            }
            GUESTS.get("CRAFT").setEnabled("true");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe not enough code here. Why does GUESTS use "view.findViewById" and the other (that works) use just "(implied this) . findViewById" ? Are they really both getting the same object? My guess is not, and that you're putting "null" or something to GUESTS.

Comment: I have several button and and edittext pairs that when you click the button, I want to get handle for paired editText.  however, using the findViewById(...) requires the "id" of the edittext object (in this case R.Id.craftGuest)  I was hoping to be able to set the EditText object in an array and then use that array later to gain access to the paired editText. (if there is a better way to do this, please let me know).

Comment: *What* is the exception/error? I don't think you understood that comment. There is a difference between `view.findViewById(id)` and `findViewById(id)`. You've said the second works, which means the `view` here is not the same

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
GUESTS.get("CRAFT").setEnabled("true");
```

By

```
((EditText)GUESTS.get("CRAFT")).setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this works:

```
EditText craftGuest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.craftGuest);
craftGuest.setEnabled("true");
```

Why don't you do something like this:

```
EditText craftGuest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.craftGuest);
GUESTS.put("CRAFT", craftGuest);
GUESTS.get("CRAFT").setEnabled("true");
```

Or simplifying:

```
GUESTS.put("CRAFT", (EditText) findViewById(R.id.craftGuest));
GUESTS.get("CRAFT").setEnabled("true");
```

I think that your problem here is the ***view.*** before the ***findBiewById*** .

And one more note: the ***.setEnabled*** method is waiting for a boolean value. In you case you have a String value ("true"). The correct code would be:

```
public HashMap<String,EditText> GUESTS = new HashMap<String,EditText)();

GUESTS.put("CRAFT", (EditText) findViewById(R.id.craftGuest));
GUESTS.get("CRAFT").setEnabled(true); // true without quotation marks
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that and I will let you know. (helps sometimes with other eyes.